# How to upgrade diamondback RC to Release? (gentoo)

Tags: ros, gentoo, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed on Gentoo like so:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Gentoo

How would I best upgrade things? Do I just need to run the rosinstall line again? Is there some command to rebuild everything that I should run afterwards?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9325/how-to-upgrade-diamondback-rc-to-release?-(gentoo)/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running the `rosinstall` again should work.

It's easiest to use the [update option](http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall#Updating_a_rosinstall_tree) of rosinstall, like this:

```
$ rosinstall ~/ros
```

(Assuming you had installed it to `~/ros` initially.)

You probably do not need to rebuild everything, just the parts you actually depend on. To do that, run `rosmake` on your packages or stacks in the normal way.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-10**:
Note we are transitioning to using versioned rosinstall targets.  You can run `rosinstall ~/ros http://URL_OF_ORIGINAL_ROSINSTALL` to get the new version.  Where URL_OF_ORIGINAL_ROSINSTALL comes from the part of the wiki page you followed previously.